# Mocking without using inerfaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is there any way to use moq without definig interfaces??
I had try to use with method that i am testing.

```
var real = new SubCoreClass();
var mock = new Mock<SubCoreClass>();
```

But i got error in Setup:

```
mock.Setup(t => t.method(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>()));
```

: Invalid setup on a non-virtual

Comment: I do believe that any abstract class and virtual methods in any class can be mocked. In short, `method()` needs to be either virtual or abstract.

Comment: You can use Moq to mock abstract methods or virtual methods as well as interfaces (all of which are counted as virtual methods), but I suspect that's not the answer you're looking for. It just won't work with non-virtual methods, since then there is nothing for Moq to override/implement.

Comment: Any mocking-framework just *overrides* all virtual members/interface members. If there´s no such member, there´s no way to override the member.